# Response.readEntity() missing in Jersey 2.17?

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jersey-2.0

I'm getting crazy regarding JAX-RS 2 usage (Jersey 2.17). I migrated from JAX-RS 1.0 and some texts posted here are explaining to use response.readEntity(Class.class). But this method is missing in Jersey 2.17. Is its documentation outdated? How could I extract an entity from Response?

Comment: It's still there. Make sure you aren't using the old API still.

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem in my pom.xml . It was a outdated glassfish-embedded-web with a conflict in Jersey. I removed it and now it's working fine.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue with Websphere and not using maven. I am adding jars as shared lib. Could you pls explain a bit more so that i can be able to device a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am using jersey-server, jersey-client, jersey-container-servlet-core, all 3 of version 2.23.1. Please make sure you have imported javax.ws.rs-api version 2.0.1 or later. I had not imported it in my build.gradle. After importing, I was able to see readEntity method for my Response class.